# Bind an element of Array to a xaml property

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Before I get a duplicate question, I just want to say I can't seem to find a solution to my problem at all. All I want to do is bind an element of an array to a property and can't seem to figure out how because of my lack of experience.

Here is how my C# code looks:

> ```
> public class MainPageImplement : INotifyPropertyChanged
> {
>     BitmapImage[] weatherIconSource = new BitmapImage[7];
>     public BitmapImage[] WeatherIconSource
>     {
>         get { return weatherIconSource; }
>         set
>         {
>             weatherIconSource = value;
>             NotifyPropertyChanged("WeatherIconSource");
>         }
>     }
>     private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
>     {
>         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
>     }
>
>     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
> }
> ```

Here is how my XAML property looks:

> ```
>        <Image Grid.Column="1" Name="WeatherIconZero" Source="{x:Bind PropertyName.WeatherIconSource[0], Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
> ```

My code executes without any errors to go off of but does not actually bind anything. However, it works just fine if I used BitmapImage variable and not an element from array.

Comment: How are you setting the `WeatherIconSource` property? Because if you modify each index individually (ie `WeatherIconSource[0] = myBitmap;`), then you will not notify property changes to the UI. You will save yourself a whole lot of pain if you simply use `ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>`. Arrays do not communicate changes to the UI.

Comment: Could I say I have a "series" of methods that work to get the right property? Some of these methods are also shared by other properties. In order to update the UI I set up a timer to call a method that updates these arrays. Whenever it updates the arrays there is a 'set' that calls PropertyChanged to update the UI. This works flawlessly when I don't use arrays and give each property a unique path. However, if I was to use arrays it makes my code look better and save hundreds of lines of code. Edit: I should add I am updating the UI at certain times of day that runs on a different thread.

Comment: Ok, my answer below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are not bindable to the UI, at least not per index. You need to use an `ObservableCollection<T>`:

```
public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> WeatherIconSource { get; } = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();
```

Don't bother using arrays; you cannot notify a single-index property change

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("WeatherIconSource[5]"); // Doesn't work.
```

If you're stuck with arrays, then you have to notify property changed on the entire collection whenever you update a single index:

```
WeatherIconSource[5] = myNewBitmap;
NotifyPropertyChange("WeathIconSource"); // Updates all [0] [1] ... [n]
```

But if you do this, you will force a refresh on all indexes. All your images will redraw. You may get away with this if your app is simple with small images; otherwise, make the change to `ObservableCollection<T>`.

If you have hardcoded bindings with an exact index, like this:

```
Source="{x:Bind PropertyName.WeatherIconSource[0], Mode=OneWay}"
Source="{x:Bind PropertyName.WeatherIconSource[2], Mode=OneWay}"
Source="{x:Bind PropertyName.WeatherIconSource[5], Mode=OneWay}"
```

then instantiate your collection like this so you don't get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`:

```
public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> WeatherIconSource { get; } = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>
{
    null, // [0]
    null, // [1]
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null  // [6]
};
```

Comment: This is such a beautiful solution. It works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It should be,

```
`<Image Grid.Column="1" Name="WeatherIconZero"  Source="{Binding weatherIconSource[0]}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" /`>
```

Comment: I should add that I have tried that but had the same results.

Comment: I just tried it again and I stand corrected. Is there something wrong with my NotifyPropertyChanged method possibly?